# How to get the number of times a query execute

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP, is there a way to get the total number of times a query was executed in 24 hours?

Comment: what you have tried?? Show some efforts...

Comment: and what do you mean by 24 hours??? does that query run in a single page? in a single run?? or the page gets called multiple times??? if so than you need to **use a db table to keep track on that**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try having an extra table. Lets name it `executetb` with column:

- `exid` (`int`, *primary* and *auto-increment*)
- `executionnumber` (`int`)
- `datetimeexec` column (which should have a `datetime` data type)

If your page is access, your system should run a query that would check if there is an existing data in your `executetb` for today. And standby the current number of execution before you run your main query:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");

if($stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT exid, executionnumber FROM executetb WHERE DATE(datetimeexec) = ? ")){
  $stmt->bind_param("s",$today);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
  $check = $stmt->num_rows;

    if($check == 0){ /* IF NO EXISTING DATA FOR TODAY */
      $exact = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); /* GET CURRENT DATE AND TIME */
      $executionnumber = 0; /* START WITH 0 */
      if($stmt2 = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO executetb (executionnumber, datetimeexec) VALUES (?)")){
        $stmt2->bind_param("is",$executionnumber,$exact);
        $stmt2->execute();
        $exid = $stmt2->insert_id; /* GET THE INSERTED ID */
        $stmt2->close();
      } /* END OF CREATING A DATA FOR TODAY */
    } /* END OF IF NO EXISTING DATE FOR TODAY */

    else { /* ELSE, IF THERE IS ALREADY A DATA FOR TODAY */
      $stmt->bind_result($exid,$executionnumber); /* GET THE CURRENT EXECUTION NUMBER FOR TODAY */
      $stmt->fetch();
    }

  $stmt->close();
} /* END OF PREPARED STATEMENT */
```

And use an `if()` statement when you execute your query:

```
if($stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT column FROM table")){ /* WHEN THE STATEMENT IS TRUE */
  $stmt->execute();
  $executionnumber = $executionnumber + 1; /* INCREMENT THE CURRENT NUMBER OF EXECUTION */
  mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE executetb SET executionnumber = $executionnumber WHERE exid = '$exid'"); /* THEN UPDATE THE EXECUTION TABLE */
  $stmt->close();
}
```

### Function:

To put it in a function, just create a function:

```
function execute($today){
  /* PUT HERE THE FIRST CODE I'VE PROVIDED EXCEPT FOR THE DATE TODAY */

  return $executionnumber;
}
```

And to call your function:

```
if(/* YOUR MAIN STATEMENT QUERY HERE */){

  $today = date("Y-m-d");
  $numberofexec = execute($today);
  $numberofexec = $numberofexec + 1;

  mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE executetb SET executionnumber = '$numberofexec' WHERE DATE(datetimeexec) = '$today'");

} /* END OF YOUR MAIN STATEMENT */
```

Comment: I was hoping for some php function, if any. But, this also helped. Thanks :)

Comment: @KumariManisha - Updated my answer if you want it in a function.

Comment: @KumariManisha I have updated my answer, You can get it by only a single query.

Answer (score 0):

Create another record in the database and start its value from zero and write another simple function lets call updateCount(), updateCount() will be called when you execute your query. And the updateCount() will have a simple sql query that will increment the record by 1 every time  your query main query executes.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by count no. of query appeard in general_log from last 1 day. for example- 
first enable general log & output to table.

```
SET global general_log = 1;
SET global log_output = 'table';
```

then run the query

```
select count(*) from mysql.general_log where timestampdiff(second,event_time,now()) <= 86400 and argument ='select * from test where id=4';
    +----------+
    | count(*) |
    +----------+
    |        3 |
    +----------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```